# How to find which process made this network requests

Tags: windows, networking, security, tracking, fiddler

I was running fiddler and suddenly I see requests this requests to

hxxp://zc.qq.com/cgi-bin/chs/numreg/init?

and

hxxp://www.baidu.com/cache/global/img/gs-2.0.gif

But no process is shown. How do I Identify which process made the requests.
This seem to be tracking requests. Both request's responses try to set cookies.
But I don't remember installing anything related to qq and baidu.
More Information: I stay in India. OS: Win7.1

[image: Fiddler Screenshot zx.qq.com]

This requests seem to be repeated after around 6 minutes
I tried TCPView.

Comment: Please see my answer [How do I find out which program and process ID accesses a given IP address in Windows?](http://superuser.com/a/877885)

Comment: I checked it using  TCPVIEW. but I was not able to identify the process. I am checking it now with TCPLOGVIEW

Comment: Make sure you are running the tools as administrator

Comment: Yes sure. Only problem is I was able to identify this because I was using fiddler. Tcplogview doesn't show URL. I have to keep waiting for the event to occur

Comment: No, but it does show remote host if not the full URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to identify what process was creating this requests using the linked answer.

Finally I installed Comodo Firewall. Then I was able to identify that I was regularly receiving requests over the internet to port 8888 which was my fiddler listening port.

But still a problem remains, I have Dynamic IP allocated.
And I am still getting this requests even when my IP changes.

**TL;DR:** When you are unable to identify the process making the request.
there is remote chance that the request was initiated by another machine.