# How do I find out which program and process ID accesses a given IP address in macOS?

Tags: macos, ip, network-monitoring

Is it possible to identify which program on a Mac is accessing a specific IP address?

I found my computer is contacting what have been identified as malicious addresses and wish to investigate each one.

May be it is possible to set up some audit for this?

---

NOTE: this is essentially the same question as this one:

[How do I find out which program and process ID accesses a given IP address in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/877879/how-do-i-find-out-which-program-and-process-id-accesses-a-given-ip-address-in-wi)

But I'm looking for info regarding Macs rather than Windows. My apologies to user Dims for cribbing most of the text of his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a persistent connection and is currently open, you can find the program with the `lsof` ("list open files") command and its `-i` ("internet") option. You'll need `sudo` to see programs running under other users. For example, to show all processes with open connections to the address 1.2.3.4, you could use:

```
sudo lsof -i 1.2.3.4
```

The "command" field in its output is pretty short, but the second field is the process ID number, and you can use that to get more info, either with command-line tools like `ps` or the graphical Activity Monitor utility.

If it's only connecting intermittently, you probably need an additional firewall program. [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) is a longstanding favorite for this, and it can show an alert when a new outgoing connection is detected and let you decide whether to allow or block it.

There's also a free & open source alternative, [LuLu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html), by Objective-See (aka Patrick Wardle). Actually, he has [several other security tools that might be helpful](https://objective-see.com/products.html).

And it's not particularly related to Internet connections, but I'd recommend scanning your Mac with [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/).

Comment: Many thanks for the thoughtful and comprehensive answer. Ultimately, Little Snitch turned out to be the right tool for the job. For those who may be interested, it turned out that something had worked its way into my Opera (the browser) profile and was dialing an unapproved and highly suspicious IP address. I was able to rid myself of the problem by ditching the profile and building a new one from scratch (easy).